# Is it alright to ask about where to acquire a certain piece of hardware?

Tags: discussion

Specific example I was pondering asking about.

[Pastilda](https://www.crowdsupply.com/third-pin/pastilda) is a nifty piece of hardware. However, the people who created the CrowdSupply campaign are no longer offering it for purchase. I have not found any other place to purchase it or something like successor product.

The product is open hardware, but definitely something I'm up to "soldering" (besides, I have no way to print the PCB).

So my question(s):

- Is it fine to ask about where to acquire this hardware, even though I have a specific product already in mind?
- Is it okay to ask where to acquire a specific product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, where to get something is not on-topic here.

Comment: Keep in mind, though that in this case the question would not be should I go to shop XYZ, but rather something like: "who can get me this hardware _built_ based on these open hardware specs" ... I think that's still quite a difference. But I'll take your word as a mod for it 

Comment: When asking for recommendations, I have often mentioned that I am in country X (changes about once a year), and that postage is a consideration.